# ajax loading into the jqPlot

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays, jqplot

I need to make a chart using a jqPlot with data array like

```
[[2010-06-30 18:40:11, 18], [2010-06-30 18:42:17, 25]...]
```

it works great with the official example for "dateAxisRenderer plugin"

but now i need to make ajax-loaded chart. it seems to me that "AJAX JSON Data Renderer" method can't use dates as a "x" data source and only can take "y" values from simple [y1,y2,y3] array. how can i make him to take both coords from my array - date for "x" and number for "y"?
JSON example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var ajaxDataRenderer = function(url, plot, options) {
var ret = null;
$.ajax({
  async: false,
  url: url,
  dataType:"json",
  success: function(data) {
    ret = data;
  }}
);
return ret;
};

var jsonurl = "jsondata.php";

var plot2 = $.jqplot('chart2', jsonurl,{
  title: "AJAX JSON Data Renderer",
  dataRenderer: ajaxDataRenderer,
  dataRendererOptions: {
    unusedOptionalUrl: jsonurl
  }
  });
});
```

thanks.

Comment: Can you post some example code?

Answer (score 2):

The basic issue in your code is renderer is not returning the response received form the ajax request. Success function call sets the variable after returning it.

Take a look at the code below.

**Steps of execution:**

1. Call the `plot` function on page load
2. make the ajax request
3. on success of the request call the `renderer` with response data
4. call `jqplot` with arguments form the response data.
5. graph rendered

---

```
var ajaxJqPlot = {
    settings : {
        data_url : "jsondata.php",
        element_id : "chart2"
    },
    plot : function(settings){
        t = this;
        $.extend(t.settings, settings);
        $.ajax({
            async : false,
            url : t.settings.data_url,
            dataType :"json",
            success : t.renderer
        });
    },
    renderer : function(res){
        t = this;
        $.jqplot(t.settings.element_id,  res.data, res.opt);
    }
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    ajaxJqPlot.plot();
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Why this is not marked as correct answer? :)